# What's a good tool to create 2D geometry figures?

Tags: image-editing

What is a good tool to create geometry figures in elementary geometry textbooks (dealing with subjects such as triangles, circles, Pythagorean theorem and Ptolemy's theorem)?

P.S. Anyone with sufficient reputation may tag this question with `geometry`, which is a new tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also [Dr Geo](http://www2.ofset.org/drgeo). From the web site:

> Dr. Geo is a GTK interactive geometry
>   software. It allows one to create
>   geometric figure plus the interactive
>   manipulation of such figure in respect
>   with their geometric constraints. It
>   is usable in teaching situation with
>   students from primary or secondary
>   level.
>
> Dr. Geo integrates advanced features
>   as an integrated Scheme programming
>   language to define scripts within a
>   figure. The language is also used to
>   define functionnaly interactive
>   figure.

Answer (score 1):

MS Visio is always a good choice.  I doubt it will outperform an application designed specifically for geometry but I do thing it makes up for it in other features that will spice up your drawings.

[MS Visio Homepage](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio/FX100487861033.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html). It produces vector graphics, integrates with TeX for mathematical formulae and captions. I've used it to produce teaching aids.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I would use [OpenOffice.org](http://www.openoffice.org/)'s Draw program.  It's a simple, free solution part of the OpenOffice project. It lets you draw simple shapes easily enough and then you can put text around the shapes as needed to show the different parts of formulas and such.